# Split data in R with two specific values of column

Tags: r

The following code takes the data of all the rows in which LABEL =0. How to modify it if I need to take the rows for both 0 and 4 in the LABEL column.

```
dt<- read.csv("log1.csv")
dt
dt_inactivity <- dt[dt$LABEL==0),]
dt_inactivity
```

Comment: `dt_inactivity <- dt[dt$LABEL %in% c(0, 4),]`

Comment: Use in: `dt_inactivity <- dt[ dt$LABEL %in% c(0, 4), ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using *dplyr*, this should do what you want :

```
library(dplyr)

dt_inactivity <- filter(dt, LABEL == 0 | LABEL == 4)
```

See full documentation here : https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html